# Changing types passed in to virtual methods

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding, virtual

I have a question regarding changing parameter types in virtual methods. First I'll explain the scenario.

This is the base interface for users that can execute commands

```
public interface IUserThatExecutesCommands
{
   bool IsInRole(string role);
}
```

This is an extension of that base interface, that requires users to have the concept of Eminence

```
public interface IUserThatExecutesEminenceCommands : IUserThatExecutesCommands
{
   int Eminence { get; }
}
```

Now this is the base abstract UserCommand class that defines commands that `IUserThatExecutesCommands` use

```
public abstract class UserCommand
{
   public virtual bool CanBeExecutedBy(IUserThatExecutesCommands user)
   {
       // For the purpose of simplification I have not included the actual implementation of this method.
       return UserIsInOneOfAllowedRoles(user);
   }
}
```

Here is an extension of that class that introduces the concept of Eminence, thus requires a `IUserThatExecutesEminenceCommands` to use. At the moment this causes a compiler error because I have changed the type of use that is passed in.

```
public abstract class EminenceCommand : UserCommand
{
        public override bool CanBeExecutedBy(IUserThatExecutesEminenceCommands user)
        {
            return user.Eminence >= _requiredEminence;
        }
}
```

My question is, is there a way that I can override the `CanBeExecutedBy` function so that I can change the type of user that is passed in? I want to be able to extend the UserCommand class, but at the moment I am unable to due to this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public abstract class EminenceCommand : UserCommand 
{ 
        public override bool CanBeExecutedBy(IUserThatExecutesCommands user) 
        { 
            // Dynamically check the type of user passed in and only check priveleges if correct type
            IUserThatExecutesEminenceCommands u = user as IUserThatExecutesEminenceCommands;
            if( u == null) {
                 return false;
            }
            return u.Eminence >= _requiredEminence; 
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you establish a signature for a virtual function, it becomes a contract that you cannot change. However, you can test the `user` argument to `CanBeExecutedBy` and see if it supports any desired interface. So, your method would look like this:

```
public override bool CanBeExecutedBy(IUserThatExecutesCommands user)
{
    IUserThatExecutesEminenceCommands u = user as IUserThatExecutesEminenceCommands;
    if (u == null)
    {
        // TODO: Ignore the arg, throw an exception or do something else.
        return false;
    }

    return u.Eminence >= _requiredEminence;
}
```